EFCore 8.0.3 - Navigation Property With a Composite Key
I'm building up my DB using code first EFCore.  Trying to do most of the work in navigation properties on the entities (but will also add some fluentAPI lines where needed).  For the most part I've managed to get by but getting a strange scenario when joining two tables where I have a composite key as the join.
Initially I noticed there was a unique index on WeekScore to UserId.  When I changed the WeekScore to a ICollection<> and ran a migration it removed the unique constraint but I have to go round my code and account for the list of weekscores (when there will only ever be 1)
public class WeekScore : BaseEntity
{
    public int WeekScoreId { get; set; }
    
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    
    public int WeekNo { get; set; }
    
    public int Score { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties

    public User User { get; set; } = null!;

    #endregion
}

public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;

    //...

    #region Navigation Properties

    public WeekScore? WeekScore { get; set; }

    #endregion
}

Sample data from this table

Although technically a User will have many WeekScores (determined by weekNo), I'll only ever want to get one back for a given WeekNo - hence the lack of List<> on the User entity.
However, EFCore is trying to be smart and in my tests - when adding multiple rows to the WeekScore table with the same UserId (different WeekNo), it's bumping off the latest record with the same UserId.
Is there a way I can maintain the single WeekScore record on User (using either nav property or fluentAPI) so I can do something like:
var scores = await _db.User.AsNoTracking()
    .Include(x => x.WeekScore)
    .Where(x => x.WeekScore.WeekNo == weekNo)
    .ToListAsync();


You're specifying a one-to- one relationship, while what you describe is actually a one-to-many relationship. There will not be "only 1" week score: there will be 1 week score per week.

@JHBonarius Thank you.  I think I understood that part of my problem but still wondered if it was possible to flatten the WeekScore into a single property rather than a list.  It is currently working as a list so I guess I can just continue with that

"I'll only ever want to get one back for a given WeekNo" - sounds like a business scenario which should not be translated to the entity level. Create appropriate DTO/Domain model and fetch it accordingly.

@GuruStron very good point.  Thanks for your input.  Will change the entity class to reflect the proper relationship and work out the rest in my Mapper profile
